# Are the Fourier coefficients of $\eta(q^m)^m / \eta(q)$ non-negative?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, partitions

In [this paper](http://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/11094/3071/1/PRIMS41_3_683.pdf), the following result is proved.

For any prime $p$, all the Fourier coefficients of

$$\eta(q^p)^p / \eta(q) = q^{\frac{p^2-1}{12}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - q^{pn})^p (1 - q^{n})^{-1}$$

are non-negative.

As seeing [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A175595), I conjectured

all the Fourier coefficients of

$$\eta(q^m)^m / \eta(q) = q^{\frac{m^2-1}{12}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - q^{mn})^m (1 - q^{n})^{-1}$$

are non-negative for any positive integer $m$, .

Is this conjecture true?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes this is true and these Fourier coefficients actually enumerate some combinatorial objects called $m$-cores. These are partitions with no hooklength divisible by $m$. In fact for $m\geq 4$ these coefficients are positive. This last result was proved in ["Defect zero $p-$blocks for finite simple groups"](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-01/S0002-9947-96-01481-X/home.html), by Granville and Ono.

I want to also point out that Saito's conjecture on nonnegativity of particular eta quotients (which was the subject of the paper you link to) has been fully proven in ["K. Saito's Conjecture for Nonnegative Eta Products and Analogous Results for Other Infinite Products"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702027) by Berkovich and Garvan.

Comment: By the way, "$t$-core" is a more common term when $t$ isn't specified.

Comment: @DouglasZare I thought it largely depends on the field. For example I almost always see "t-core" in number theory/hypergeometric literature, and "n-core" in algebraic geometry/representation theory literature. Either way, here I was just trying to match the OP's choice.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to give a term that will produce more hits than $m$-core in a search.